# Does Google has schema conversion tool for BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

So far we are using Teradata as our datawarehouse. 
We want to migrate our solution to BigQuery.

Does Google has schema conversion tool for BigQuery something like [AWS Schema Conversion Tool](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/SchemaConversionTool/)?

Comment: Have you read this? A quick search: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/teradata-to-gcp

Comment: @GrahamPolley - Yes, but it does not mention anything about conversion tool

Comment: That's because there isn't one. But, it describes how to export and import using other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "direct" conversion tool straight from Teradata to BQ. But in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/teradata-to-gcp#stage1), it mentioned what tools you will use (Informatica, talend, or other partner tools) that would transform the data into BQ-friendly versions. You basically export it, make sure it's BQ compatible, then import it into BQ.